# Trouble Pulling Images from Self-Hosted Private GitLab Registry in Kubeflow Pipelines on k3s/WSL2

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, kubeflow, kubernetes-secrets

I am new on Kubernetes and Kubeflow and trying to pull images from my self hosted private gitlab registry in Kubeflow Pipelines. This is my pipeline:

```
@container_component
def container_component_trial(sentence_count:str, output_gcs: Output[Dataset]):
    return ContainerSpec(
        image='gitex.xx:latest',
        command=[
            'python3',
            'sentence_generator_app.py',
        ],
        args=[
            '--output_path', output_gcs.path,
            '--sentence_count', sentence_count
        ]
    )

@pipeline(name='container-running-pipeline')
def my_pipeline():
    component = container_component_trial(sentence_count = "5")

compiler.Compiler().compile(
        pipeline_func=my_pipeline,
        package_path='./my_pipeline.yaml')
```

I am using k3s on WSL2 Ubuntu. I created secret key using this command:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry gitlab-registry-secret \
> --docker-server=gitex.xx \
> --docker-username=my_username \
> --docker-password=my_password\
> --docker-email=yy@xx \
-n kubeflow
```

I then patched this secret to the service account, to ensure it's added to every pod created

```
kubectl patch serviceaccount pipeline-runner \
>   -p "{\"imagePullSecrets\": [{\"name\": \"gitlab-registry-secret\"}]}" \
> -n kubeflow
```

Despite this, when I trigger a pipeline run, I receive the Error: ErrImagePull error, indicating that my pods cannot pull the required images from the GitLab registry.

Additional information:

1. I can pull images using the same credentials using docker.
2. I can ping the gitlab host machine from a pod in my machine.

I am totally stuck at this part. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: in your first command you need to specify the namespace `-n kubeflow`

Comment: Thank you for the reminder but unfortunately created using -n kubeflow but didn't specify in the question. My secret is created for kubeflow namespace:

Comment: Can you tell me the result of `kubectl get secret gitlab-registry-secret --output="jsonpath={.data.\.dockerconfigjson}" | base64 --decode`

Comment: and can you provide me the `default-editor serviceaccount conf` in your kubeflow namespace

Comment: Are you looking for this output: `apiVersion: v1
imagePullSecrets:
- name: gitlab-registry-secret
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-08-14T10:16:59Z"
  name: default
  namespace: kubeflow
  resourceVersion: "1363751"
  uid: 96a22987-27e8-4668-a489-afb40156c284`

Comment: I also added my pipeline script to the question. Maybe problem is because of it.

Comment: sorry I'm looking for the `serviceAccounts` on your kubeflow user namespace, there is 3 `default default-editor default-viewer`, give me the conf of your `default-editor`

Comment: Thank you so much for all your attention and time. I just realized that the port information is missing in my gitlab server. So when creating the secret, I need to pass gitex.xx:1234 rather than gitex.xx. Problem is solved after this change.